# Changing out old two wire switch to new three wire grounded switch

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install a modern plug switch in kitchen to combine light and plug in. To a old two wire single pole switch with no ground.

Comment: So what is your question? You can pull a separate ground to create a grounded circuit, or install a GFCI receptacle, the receptacle will not be grounded but is code compliant in many states and n reality a GFCI protected circuit is safer than a grounded circuit when considering risk to people.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Not unusual.  If the box is metal, the ground wires will go to the box, not the switch.  Even today that is how you install switches. Receps are a bit more complicated.

Comment: Is there a neutral in the switch box? In older wiring there may or may not be a neutral in a switch box. The existing switch may have a white wire on one contact, but for old switches this white will not be a neutral. However if there are other whites in the box not connected to the switch, those may be neutrals.

Answer (score 2):

You can't anyway.

### Kitchen lighting is not allowed on kitchen receptacle circuits.

By putting a receptacle on a lighting circuit,  you are creating a code violation.

Now, if the kitchen wiring was done at a time before this was required, and permits were pulled, then the kitchen wiring *as it is now* is "grandfathered".  It's allowed to continue in service even though it would never be approved today, because it was legal at the time.   **This is not license to modify it**.

Modifications must meet Code at the time they are installed. Today, kitchen/pantry/dining area receptacles must be on 20A circuits which are dedicated to serving receptacles in those areas, with no other loads allowed except for auxiliary electric loads on a gas range, and a wall clock.  There must be at least 2 such circuits, but the inspector would surely let you slide on that if you were only installing a couple of additional receptacles.

Since the circuit you are speaking of has a hardwired light on it, you can't add a kitchen receptacle to it.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two wires going to the switch, you cannot add an outlet. What you have right now is a hot and a switched hot. The outlet would require a hot and a **neutral** as well as a ground.

Since I don't know where you are located, the rest of this answer applies to the USA:

You could get away without a ground by using a GFCI outlet, although the electrical code only really allows that for retrofitting an existing two-wire outlet. Since you'd need to add a neutral anyway, it's really not allowed.

Depending on the construction, adding a neutral and ground could be difficult or not. If you have wires in conduit, it should be fairly easy to add a neutral wire and the conduit should act as ground. If you have multi-wire cable in the wall, you would need to pull new cable which could require opening up the wall. A photograph of the inside of the switch box could help determine this.